# Matplotlib fails to generate plot when using tex with newline character in xtick labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am generating a figure with multiple levels of xtick labels. I could achieve that by having an extra label with new line character. But the approach does not work if I use tex in plot generation, with an error telling my a .dvi file in tex.cache is missing. I found that the tex file exists but latex does not produce a dvi file because there is no page to produce.

When using tex, the code works perfectly if I change `ax.set_xticklabels(labels + ["\nA to C"])` to `ax.set_xticklabels(labels + ["A to C"])` or `ax.set_xticklabels(labels + ["DummyText\nA to C"])`.

How can I generate the graph successfully using matplotlib+tex with newline character in xtick labels?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import numpy

# There will be errors in code if I uncomment the following
# matplotlib.rc('text', usetex = True)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 1, squeeze=False)
ax = axs[0, 0]
labels = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
data1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
data2 = [1.5,2.5,2.5,3.5,7]
total_categories = len(data1)

width = 1
data1_color = '#fc8d62'
data2_color = '#66c2a5'
props = {'connectionstyle':'bar','arrowstyle':'-',\
                 'shrinkA':20,'shrinkB':20,'linewidth':2}

center_positions = numpy.arange(0,total_categories) * 2.5
ax.bar(center_positions - 0.5, data1, width=width, color=data1_color, align='center', edgecolor='black', hatch='//', label="Data1")
ax.bar(center_positions + 0.5, data2, width=width, color=data2_color, align='center', edgecolor='black', label="Data2")

# Setting xticks
ax.set_xticks(numpy.concatenate((center_positions, numpy.array([2.5]))))
ax.set_xticklabels(labels + ["\nA to C"])
ax.set_xticks([-1.25, 6.25, 8.75, 11.25], minor=True)
ax.tick_params( axis='x', which='minor', direction='out', length= 45)
ax.tick_params( axis='x', which='major', bottom='off', top='off' )
ax.set_xlim(-1.25, 11.25)
ax.set_xlabel("Methods", size=15)

ax.legend()
fig.savefig("Temp.pdf")
```

[image: Target output]

```latex
% tex file auto generated by matplotlib
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{type1cm}



\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[papersize={72in,72in},body={70in,70in},margin={1in,1in}]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\fontsize{10.000000}{12.500000}{\sffamily } % When there are other texts, a dvi file will be generated
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\n` is not a valid linebreak in latex. So matplotlib translates it to such. But it probably cannot (or at least doesn't do it) when it's at the start of a string. I suppose it would not throw an error with something like `[r"\ \\ A to C"]` (translate as "space linebreak ..."), but it would then also show the string in the same line as the one above. You could also bring this up on  https://discourse.matplotlib.org to see if some more expert people have an idea.